# Download all files from a Moodle course as a student

Tags: moodle

I don't know if this is the correct site for this.

I would like to have an efficient way to download all the files that in a course. As a student I can of course not change anything about the Moodle installation.

Comment: I’m sure not many users are familiar with Moodle. Could you perhaps provide a (partial) screenshot of the page were course files are available for download? Are the links direct links to the files?

Comment: Have you asked the course administrator/instructor? Do you have permission to download them?

Comment: @DavidPostill:  If you're enrolled in the course, and you're downloading the files for personal use only, of course you can download them.  In such a case, no permission is needed.  But, if you share them with others who are not enrolled in the course, that might violate copyright law.  Also, if you upload them to [Course Hero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_Hero), OneClass, or any other public place, that too might violate copyright law.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I found was to use the [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) Firefox extension. Go to the course page, fast filter for `resource/view.php`, check the `All files` and `Disable others` boxes. That way I was able to download all files, including source code text files which might have odd file extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [MoodleDownloader](https://github.com/harsilspatel/moodle-downloader), [Moodle Buddy](https://github.com/marcelreppi/moodle-buddy) (both are browser extensions) or [Moodle-DL](https://github.com/C0D3D3V/Moodle-DL).